# Avoiding "Can't find project or library" on computer without app installed

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel file which contains one module which refers to Powerpoint.

I want to use the other modules in this file on a server which does not have Powerpoint installed (long story...), but cannot do this without incurring the dreaded *Can't find project or library* error message.

Of course I can simply create another version with the offending module deleted, which obviously works fine. 

However, there are several reasons why I don't want to do this, not least that I really don't want to have to maintain multiple versions if I can help it.

Is there any way around this, e.g. getting Excel to ignore this module and not try to compile it unless it is called?

I have waded through 41 posts on stackoverflow on this topic, without finding anything that helps, which makes me suspect that I am asking the impossible.

There are some suggestions that late binding might help, but it does not seem to make any difference.  Here is the offending code:

```
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
  Err.Clear
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
  End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

None of the other modules make any reference to Powerpoint.

Comment: Could you simply comment the culprit lines? Or are you using these on another computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there any way around this, e.g. getting Excel to ignore this module and not try to compile it unless it is called?*

You could try *conditional compilation*, that's pretty much exactly what it does.

Open up the *project properties* dialog, and define a project-level conditional compilation constant:

[image: Project Properties dialog]

Now wrap the PowerPoint-dependent module with `#If` directives:

```
Option Explicit
#If HAS_POWERPOINT = 1 Then
'... entire module body ...
#End If
```

Then, everywhere you have a piece of code that calls into the conditionally-compiled module, surround it with `#If` directives:

```
#If HAS_POWERPOINT = 1 Then
    MyProcedureThatRunsOffPowerPoint "foo", "bar", 42
#Else
    'PowerPoint-dependent module doesn't exist, what do we do instead?
#End If
```

Now when you distribute the macro to the machine that doesn't have PowerPoint installed, you go to *project properties* and set the constant to 0, then recompile the project.

Comment: Many thanks.  This looks to be just what I am after.  I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: I knew about conditional compilation when using different versions of Excel, 64/32 bit type stuff.  Never knew about the argument option in the properties though.  18 years with Excel and still learning.  Cheers.  :)

Comment: Very many thanks for pointing me in the direction of Conditional Compilation.  It works perfectly.  I ended up using a test of Environ$("computername") in the calling module to set #Const in the offending module, so I don't need to modify anything when using the code on different computers (I know the name of the problem one). I could even search for POWERPNT.EXE or similar to set #Const if I wanted to make it more generic, though I don't need to go that far at present. Problem solved!

Comment: @Mat'sMug : <3 Always learning stuff when I read your posts! :)